# Door Prizes - Probability

Tags: probability

Joe goes to a party with three friends. There is a drawing for four door prizes. Each person has an equal chance of wining a prize. No one can win more than one prize. If there are totally thirty people in the party, what is the probability that Joe and his friends each will win a prize?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

You are *choosing* 4 people out of a set of 30 people, without replacement, and order does not matter. There are $30\choose4$ possible ways to do that, and Joe and his friends being picked is just 1 of those ways. Thus the probability of this occurring is $$\frac{1}{30\choose4}=\frac{1}{27405}\approx0.00003648969...
$$